# My APP crashes as soon as launch on Android Emulator on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
> method 'void
> android.view.View.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)'
> on a null object reference
> at com.example.converter.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30)

```
 that's where it shows error         btnMiles.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
```

Comment: Can you show your code?

It looks like you forgot to initialize btnMiles view in your MainActivity

Comment: might be findViewById(R.id.btnMiles); is missing

Answer (score 0):

Hi please check the code, might be missing

in XML

```
    <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnMiles"
     ..../>
```

in Java

```
Button btnMiles = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnMiles);
```